# blackberry webservice

Tags: web-services, blackberry, java-me

how i call a webservice in blackberry java ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try these links:

u can try this link to get knowledge and information:

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=884

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/td-p/206242

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html

A variety of such links are also available via google and also in stack overflow.
try and search  :)